# Views not displaying on page, but show up in preview

Tags: 7, views

I have a view setup to display all properties where a drop down box = portfolio 1. However, when I set up the view everything looks correct but when I go to the actual url it does not display the teaser or full content in the body.

When I set it up as a block I can add it to my right sidebar and it displays fine...

here is the export of the view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'portfolio_1';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Portfolio_1';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Portfolio_1';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'list';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['view_mode'] = 'full';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'property' => 'property',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: portfolio (field_portfolio) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_portfolio_value']['id'] = 'field_portfolio_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_portfolio_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_portfolio';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_portfolio_value']['field'] = 'field_portfolio_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_portfolio_value']['value'] = array(
  'port1' => 'port1',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'portfolio-1';
```

I can provide screen shots if that would help.

Comment: Make sure there is no other alias 'portfolio-1'.

Answer (score 1):

Few possible things you may try to resolve the above problem are:

- Make sure the path you are accessing is same as the path you have assigned to page display.
- Not using the same path elsewhere (e.g: either in the `hook_menu`, `panels`, etc.)
- Try changing the path (adding some random chars) for testing and check if it works.
- Perform a search in the `menu_router` table for the path you are using, and if it already had an entry than you need to change the path.